# Cordova precaching the images

Tags: cordova, caching, jquery-mobile

Can I force something like precaching images in cordova project?
I mean. When my app starts, and I change page from A to B, first time (I'm using JQMobile and transition) app laggin. When I back to A and again go to B I don't have lags like before. There are some images on page B and it looks like app laggin when it runs them first time. But later app cache this images?
Can I force this caching when app starts?

Generally, this tranistions from JQMobile are little slow (I mean: lags). Maybe you guy know better solution to change page?

Best

**EDIT**
This app i SPA, and transitions look like:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div data-role="page" id="A" data-theme="a">

</div>
<div data-role="page" id="B" data-theme="a">

</div>
```

And page is changing by pagecontainer("change")

Also I'm using latest cordova version with crosswalk

Comment: Create a single page application: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/next/index.html#1-spa-is-your-friend

Comment: Please, see the edit.

Comment: Try preloading the images   --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery